# Flutter positioned widget smooth slide

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, flutter-animation

[image]

As the above picture shows i have 4 seprate areas with 4 seperate motion defined.
For example: I want to slide the positioned widget in top left to bottom right diagonal if user begins sliding at the red box. I am able to move and slide the widget the side that i want to slide but the animation of sliding is not smooth.I think that issue happens because of the wrong X and Y values to change position. So here is the code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/container.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  double? dragStartY;
  double? dragStartX;
  bool dragging = false;
  double? top;
  double? bottom;
  double? left;
  double? right;
  int? lastAction;
  double angle = 0;

  void actionDecider(double currentX, double currentY, double changeY,
      double changeX, int triggerType) {
    //0 DISMISS
    //1 LIKE
    //2 IMAGE -> 21 FORWARD - 22 BACK
    //3 SUPER LIKE
    //4 DIRECT MESSAGE
    //TRIGGER TYPE -> 0 VERTICAL - 1 HORIZONTAL

    if ((dragStartX! >= 0 && dragStartX! <= 150) &&
        (dragStartY! >= 0 && dragStartY! <= 75)) {
      if ((triggerType == 0) && (currentY > dragStartY! || changeY == 0)) {
        print(right);
        setState(() {
          lastAction = 0;
          right = right! - changeY;          
          angle = angle + math.pi / 600;
          bottom = bottom! - changeY;
          left = null;
        });
      } else if ((triggerType == 1) &&
          (currentX > dragStartX! || changeX == 0)) {
            print(right);
        setState(() {
          lastAction = 0;
          right = right! - changeX;          
          angle = angle + math.pi / 600;
          bottom = bottom! - changeX;
          left = null;
        });
      }
    } else if ((dragStartX! > 150 && dragStartX! <= 300) &&
        (dragStartY! >= 0 && dragStartY! <= 75)) {
      if ((triggerType == 0) && (currentY > dragStartY! || changeY == 0)) {
        print("left");
        print(left);
        print("cx");
        print(changeX);
        setState(() {
          lastAction = 1;
          angle = angle - math.pi / 600;
          right = null;
          left = -changeX;
        });
      } else if ((triggerType == 1) &&
          (currentX < dragStartX! || changeX == 0)) {
             print("left");
        print(left);
        print("cx");
        print(changeX);
        setState(() {
          lastAction = 1;
          angle = angle - math.pi / 600;
          right = null;
          left = -changeX;
        });
      }
    } else if ((dragStartX! >= 0 && dragStartX! <= 300) &&
        (dragStartY! > 75 && dragStartY! < 225)) {
      if (currentX > dragStartX! || changeX == 0) {
        setState(() {
          lastAction = 21;
        });
      } else if (currentX < dragStartX! || changeX == 0) {
        setState(() {
          lastAction = 22;
        });
      }
    } else if ((dragStartX! >= 0 && dragStartX! <= 300) &&
        (dragStartY! > 225 && dragStartY! <= 300)) {
      if (dragStartY! > currentY || changeY == 0) {
        setState(() {
          lastAction = 3;
        });
      }
    }
    
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        width: double.maxFinite,
        height: double.maxFinite,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Container(
              width: 300,
              height: 300,
              child: Stack(
                clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                children: [
                  Positioned(
                      child: Container(
                    width: 300,
                    height: 300,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  )),
                  Positioned(
                      right: dragging ? right : 0,
                      bottom: dragging ? bottom : 0,                     
                      child: Transform.rotate(
                        angle: angle,
                        child: GestureDetector(
                            onVerticalDragStart: (details) {
                              setState(() {
                                dragging = true;
                                dragStartX = details.localPosition.dx;
                                dragStartY = details.localPosition.dy;
                              });
                            },
                            onHorizontalDragStart: (details) {
                              setState(() {
                                dragging = true;
                                dragStartX = details.localPosition.dx;
                                dragStartY = details.localPosition.dy;
                              });
                            },
                            onVerticalDragUpdate: (details) {
                              actionDecider(
                                  details.localPosition.dx,
                                  details.localPosition.dy,
                                  details.delta.dy,
                                  details.delta.dx,
                                  0);
                            },
                            onHorizontalDragUpdate: (details) {
                              actionDecider(
                                  details.localPosition.dx,
                                  details.localPosition.dy,
                                  details.delta.dy,
                                  details.delta.dx,
                                  1);
                            },
                            onHorizontalDragEnd: (details) {
                              setState(() {
                                dragging = false;
                                dragStartX = null;
                                dragStartY = null;
                                angle = 0.0;
                                right = 0;
                                bottom = 0;
                              });
                            },
                            onVerticalDragEnd: (details) {
                              setState(() {
                                dragging = false;
                                dragStartX = null;
                                dragStartY = null;
                                angle = 0.0;
                                right = 0;
                                bottom = 0;
                              });
                            },
                            child: Container(
                              width: 300,
                              height: 300,
                              child: Stack(
                                children: [
                                  Positioned(
                                      left: 0,
                                      top: 0,
                                      child: Container(
                                        width: 150,
                                        height: 75,
                                        color: Colors.red,
                                      )),
                                  Positioned(
                                      right: 0,
                                      top: 0,
                                      child: Container(
                                        width: 150,
                                        height: 75,
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                      )),
                                  Positioned(
                                      right: 0,
                                      left: 0,
                                      top: 75,
                                      child: Container(
                                        width: 300,
                                        height: 150,
                                        color: Colors.purple,
                                      )),
                                  Positioned(
                                      left: 0,
                                      bottom: 0,
                                      child: Container(
                                        width: 300,
                                        height: 75,
                                        color: Colors.green,
                                      )),
                                ],
                              ),
                            )),
                      )),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

What should i do for slide these positioned widgets smoothly on dragUpdate events?

Comment: Instead of `Positioned` use `AnimatedPositioned`

Comment: I tried that right now but animated widget made things more complicated and not solved my problem. (Complicated: When widget is returning to the base position the colored parts are seperating from each other.)

Comment: @kemalkancetindag Everything behaves the same for me, only the animation is smoother as you wanted. You should just replace your `Positioned` which has `Transform.rotate` child with `AnimatedPositioned` and that's it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer it worked for me when i tested your solution on real device it worked.

Comment: Btw i gave duration parameter with no time like `Duration()` it can help someone who is looking for answer and don't understand what to give for `Duration()`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you don't use any animation in your code. You just change states.

Try to wrap your `Stack` in `AnimatedBuilder` or to use `AnimatedPositioned` instead of `Positioned`.

Also you can use `InteractiveViewer` (wrap your `Stack` in it), which lets you to interact with its child by dragging.

Comment: I think i might use InteractiveViewer but which parameters that i need to change in order to make smooth sliding effect

Comment: Wrap your Stack in it, then use `onPanUpdate` parameter of `GestureDetector` like this with your logics:

```dart
onPanUpdate: (tapInfo) {
          setState(() {
            xPosition += tapInfo.delta.dx;
            yPosition += tapInfo.delta.dy;
***your logics***
          });
        },
```

And also add some logics to `onPanEnd` parameter.

Comment: Thank you for answer it's working but in my case i need to have more control on widgets so AnimatedPositioned is more usefull for me.

Comment: happy to help...yes, AnimatedPositioned also requires less changes in your code

Answer (score 0):

The parent widget in this flutter app is Padding which is employing its only property padding to print an empty space of 300 px on the top of its child widget which is Stack. The alignment is set to center in the Stack widget. Stack, as it does, is taking a list of widgets as children, here it’s taking in two Positioned widgets. The first one is containing a green-colored material design message icon, which is 128 px long in width and height.